# pigeonhole principle related problem

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, pigeonhole-principle

I'm given the problem: In a tournament which 18 teams participate, a team being matched with another in a round don’t match again in the follwoing (later) rounds. After 8 rounds prove that there are 3 teams not being matched with each other.

I don't know where to start from. Can anyone help me to aproach to the solution of this problem

Comment: Let's assume there are 9 matches per round, each team playing against one other in each round.  So after 8 rounds, there have been 8*9=72 distinct pairings of the teams, and each team has played 8 distinct opposing teams.  But there are 18 teams in all, so 8 rounds doesn't allow for any team to have played all possible opponents.  Perhaps you can elaborate on "3 teams not being matched with each other".  It sounds like showing there are three teams, no two of which have played each other yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of matches needed for all teams to have faced each other exactly once is
$$\binom{18}2=153$$
Since each team should only be able to play against one team at a time, the number of distinct matches played in total is
$$9\cdot 8 = 72$$
This leaves $153-72=81$ unplayed matches.
What does your statement about "$3$ teams not being matched with each other" mean?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Well I'm afraid my professor would mean there are at least 3 teams not being matched with each other, or maybe what's the exact number of teams not being matched with each other. That made me to, too confused.