# Graph Theory: A Tournament Question

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

First of all, this is a homework question:

```
In a tournament which 18 teams participate, a team being matched with another in a
round don't match again in the following (later) rounds. After 8 rounds prove that
there are 3 teams not being matched with each other.
```

I know there is a so-called solution here [pigeonhole principle related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/644797/pigeonhole-principle-related-problem) but this does not explain "prove ... 3 teams not being matched with each other." part which is the core of the question.

By the way, this part asks to prove that 3 teams, say A,B,C, will play each other after round 8. (ie. show that there are A-B,A-C and B-C matches after round 8.)

Please, any help-hint to solve second part will be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Math SE ! I thank you for mentioning that this is homework. I am sure you will get some help. Sorry to be totally incompetent in this area (as in many other). Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that there are $9$ male teams and $9$ female teams in the tournament, and in the first $8$ rounds it just happens that all of the male teams play one another and all of the female teams play one another. In other words, it’s as if the first $8$ rounds were two round-robin tournaments running separately, one for the men and one for the women. That accounts for $2\binom92=72$ matches. Now pick any $3$ teams: at least two of them must be of the same sex, and those two have already played each other. Thus, it’s impossible in this case to find $3$ teams, no two of which have already played each other.

**Added:** However, as mualloc has pointed out, this scheme is actually not possible: $9$ is odd, so it would leave one male team and one female team sitting out each round.

Suppose that in every set of $3$ teams, two of the teams played each other in the first $8$ rounds. Let $v$ be one of the teams, and let $u_1,\ldots,u_9$ be the $9$ teams that $v$ has not played after the first $8$ rounds. Then each pair of teams in the set $\{u_1,\ldots,u_9\}$ must have played each other: if $u_k$ and $u_\ell$ have not played each other, then no two of $v,u_k$, and $u_\ell$ have played each other. But then the games that the $u_k$ played against one another account for all of their games, so the other $9$ teams must have played all of their games against one another as well, and this is the situation which we just saw is impossible. Thus, there must be a set of $3$ teams, no two of which have played one another.

Comment: @mualloc: Correct: the question is asking you to prove something that is false.

Comment: Indeed, Brian showed that the statement is false. I tried reasoning as follows: there are ${18 \choose 3}$ triangles of teams that are "good" (no edge in them has played a match), and every edge in a match kills 16 triangles (one for every team not in the match), and playing 8 rounds gives us a chance to kill $9\times 8 \times 16$ triangles, but this is more than ${18 \choose 3}$, so I supposed a configuration of matches could exist that would give a counterexample. But then I went to other questions... Well done Brian!

Comment: Thanks, @Henno. This was one of those pleasant occasions when my approach to trying to prove the result actually produced the counterexample.

Comment: @mualloc: No contradiction: I simply explained why in any $3$ teams there must be two that have already played each other. Thus, there cannot be $3$ teams such that no two of them have already played each other.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Think of two groups of 9 teams again but this time they only play against the teams of the other group for 8 weeks. That is, team1={a,b,...i} and team2={1,2,...9}. After 8 weeks, then neither team has ever played a single match inside the group. In other words, there is no a-b, a-c, and h-i match played. Actually, there are 9 teams that have never played against each other after 8 weeks. For instance, teams a, b and c have never played each other. Plus, your solution of two groups of 9 teams will allow 4 matches in a group which leaves a team alone, 9 % 2 = 1 every week.

Comment: @mualloc: You’re right. Let me think about it a bit more, and either fix it or delete it.

Comment: @mualloc: It’s fixed now. Interestingly, it turned out that the mistake is part of the actual proof!

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Can you clarify this: "But then the games that the $u_k$ played against one another account for all of their games, so the other 9 teams must have played all of their games against one another as well, and this is the situation which we just saw is impossible. " ?

Comment: @mualloc: In graph-theoretic terms $\{u_1,\ldots,u_9\}$ must be a clique in the subgraph $G$ of $K_{18}$ representing the first $8$ rounds. Every vertex of $G$ has degree $8$, so the other $9$ vertices must also form a clique. And that’s the split that we ruled out.